# Apache Derby Database euro sign

Tags: java, euro

I am saving a record with  a string that has a euro(€) sign into my derby database.

When I retrieve this record, I am getting a question mark.

Do I have to set any char set in derby db settings?

Comment: Sorry when I am sending thru a browser , in te request parameter I am getting question mark, nothing to do with derby db

Comment: try escaping the sign. when you type the url in the browser, replace all "€" in the parameter value with "%E2%82%AC".

Comment: if this question is not about derby anymore please delete it or [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12838820/edit) it to reflect the actual problem